# Mediawiki automatic "list of __" with descriptions?

Tags: mediawiki, wiki, mediawiki-extension

`list of foo` pages on Wikipedia are manually updated. Can I automate that on my own mediawiki?

I want a automatically generated `list of foo` page with a table that contains a name and description of all entries from a single category `foo`.

I could transclude the contents of the `Category:foo` page onto the list page, but this does not mean I get descriptions.
I could use [labeled section translusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Help:Labeled_section_transclusion) but this is only useful for single pages.

Can I combine the two (with an extension or otherwise)?

Answer (score 1):

[Semantic MediaWiki](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Semantic_MediaWiki) is one way to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like with [**DynamicPageList3**](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:DynamicPageList3) you can show the

- Whole Article or
- Contents of Certain Sections (Identified by
  headings) and
- Truncate title or contents to a certain maximum length

---

With [Extension:Scribunto](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto), you could write a custom Lua module and query `mw.site.stats.pagesInCategory` and fetch the the description of the [article](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:Scribunto/Lua_reference_manual#Title_objects) somehow -- depends on where and how you store the description.

---

[Extension:CategoryTree](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CategoryTree) can probably be hacked to include the first n words of an article or whatever your description consists of.